IAM Identity Center doesn'T show the its page even I enabled it to interact with it
I have followed the instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/quick-start-default-idc.html
to create a group that name is "Admin team" that has AdministratorAccess permision so there has been no problem for creating it in that time period but after creation of Admin team group; when I try to access the IAM Identity Center in my amazon account to change the permission in Admin team, I can't access the IAM Identity Center page and the page is still showing me the main page of IAM Identity Center so there is a screenshot of it: 
So I am not sure what I shold do in this case; I have inspected the page and there were some errors that I found in the console  but I couldn't understand the errors obviously and at the same time I couldn'T reach the support team of Amazon because my plan is not other than Basic Support Plan.So please help me what I can do in this situation!

You have selected an incorrect region (most likely us-east-1, which is the default), whereas your IAM Identity Center is actually configured in eu-north-1, as indicated on the page:
'IAM Identity Center is currently configured in the Europe (Stockholm) region.'

where did you see the region that my accouınt is in? I mean there is no footage related with region.

I don't know in which region you are, but the error message refers to the fact that you are in the wrong region.

I saw your point after your comment so I just tried to change the region and it is worked thanks a lot for help, by the way I will mark your comment as solved my problem.
